# Time between two dates in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a string as a date formatted yyyy-MM-dd, and I want to compare it with the current date. I'm using Android api24, and I want to be able to tell how much time has passed in a format like the first string.

I have tried with the Calendar class, something like this:

```
   val firstDate=Calendar.getInstance()
   val dateFormat=SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.getDefault())
   firstDate.time=dateFormat.parse("2001-06-04")
```

but I get stuck here, getting the current time as a calendar object.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and specifically state what your problem was. What do you mean "in a format like the first string"? The first string is a date, but you want a duration, so that doesn't make sense unless something like "1-4-8" is OK.

Comment: That is the format I'm looking for

Comment: How many days get rolled up to a month in that format? 28, 29, 30, 31? It’s kind of a nonsensical format for a span of dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can desugar to get to use the Java 8 datetime features:

[Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table?authuser=1)

Then it is really simple:

```
private fun convertFromString(datetime: String): LocalDateTime {
    val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault())
    return LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, dateTimeFormatter)
}
```